# onLongClickListener in layout with tabs

Tags: android, share, onlongclicklistener

I followed this tutorial: http://www.android4devs.com/2015/01/how-to-make-material-design-sliding-tabs.html?m=1 to make a layout with 5 tabs. Now I want to put an OnLongClickListener for a button in the first tab to make it share sound1. I have added this code in my MainActivity.java:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    button1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);

    button1.setLongClickable(true);
    button1.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onLongClick(View arg0) {
            Intent share = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
            share.setType("audio/ogg");

            Uri uri = Uri.parse("android.resource://" + getPackageName()
                    + "/raw/" + R.raw.sound1);
            share.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uri);
            startActivity(Intent.createChooser(share, "Share Sound File"));

            return true;
        }

    });
```

But that makes it crash on startup, and the logcat says this:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.view.View.setLongClickable(boolean)' on a null object reference
```

Comment: Does "activity_main" layout has Button with id "button1"?

Comment: change view with the class onLongClick method is on from new View.onLongClickListener to this probably will solve it

Comment: Davahl: uhhhh.. no. The button with id button1 is in the tab_1 layout. I'm quite new to android, but that's just a stupid mistake from me :P But I can't just paste the onCreate into the Tab1.java file. What code do I need to make it work in the Tab1.java?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using fragments. You should do that on the [Fragment](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/Fragment.html)'s [onCreateView()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/Fragment.html#onCreateView(android.view.LayoutInflater,%20android.view.ViewGroup,%20android.os.Bundle)) or [onViewCreated()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/Fragment.html#onViewCreated(android.view.View,%20android.os.Bundle)) callbacks

```
public class Tab1 extends Fragment {

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View v =inflater.inflate(R.layout.tab_1,container,false);
        button1 = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.button1);
        button1.setLongClickable(true);
        ...
        return v;
    }
}
```